# ‘Cannot modify header information’ at the very first line

Tags: php-5.3

I'm getting this very weird error. I call it weird because the full error is

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [...]/user.php:1)
```

As you can see it says that the first line of the script prints something, therefore the header is already sent. The point is that the script is:

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {
```

And nothing more! Not even a space or anything else.

I can't really understand what's wrong with it.

**Additional information**

The point is that the script works without any problem in my local webserver but not when I upload it to my hosting server.

I ran a shell script on my whole folder (with all my script) too look for whitespace at the beginning or at the end of the pages, but nothing was found.

Comment: Have you removed all whitespace and sometimes removing the closing ?> does the trick

Comment: I did. I even removed the `?>`, but no luck.

Comment: How many php pages are there?

Comment: Do you mean in my script? A lot, since I'm using CakePHP as framework. But it actually says that the output started by that script, I don't see why looking in another ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code editor, save the file without BOM.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. As far as I know it doesn't add BOM.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't. Thank you.